# Converting an alert into a magnificPopup modal

Tags: jquery, magnific-popup

Re-factoring an alert into a modal popup using magnificPopup. Not sure that I am calling magnificPopup correctly. Is this the correct syntax? Thanks for any help!

Code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.readMore').each(function () {
            if (isDivClipped(this)) {
                $(this).wrap("<div class='readmorewrapper'></div>");
                $(this).after("<a href='#' onclick='showReadMore(this);'>Read More...</a>");
            }
        });


    });
    function showReadMore(el) {
        var modalContent = ($(el).closest('.readmorewrapper').find('.readMore').text());
        $('modalContent').magnificPopup;
    }
    function isDivClipped(el) {
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Why does `isDivClipped()` always return `true`?

Comment: I think the problem is the `onclick='showReadMore(this)`. In this case, `this` is no longer referring to the `.readMore` element.

Comment: I see two errors on code,
- .magnificPopup is a function, must be called like this: .magnificPopup();
- You are saving Text into var modalContent and then trying to use that text as a Selector for $()... I think that is a mistake.

Comment: @JonathanM - set that way for future use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All related documentation: http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/

> Working Example:

```
<a class="popup-modal" href="#test-modal">Open modal</a>

<div id="test-modal" class="mfp-hide white-popup-block">
    <h1>Modal dialog</h1>
    <p>Some block of text here</p>
    <p><a class="popup-modal-dismiss" href="#">Dismiss</a></p>
</div>


$(function () {
    $('.popup-modal').magnificPopup({
        type: 'inline',
        modal: true
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.popup-modal-dismiss', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.magnificPopup.close();
    });
});
```